# Sockets used on ubuntu keep increasing

Tags: sockets, ubuntu, tcp, openfire, mina

I deployed an openfire server and a mina server on an ubuntu. I get informations below by command 
`cat /proc/net/sockstat:`

```
sockets: used 5842
TCP: inuse 17 orphan 5 tw 16 alloc 5711 mem 1165
UDP: inuse 0 mem 1
UDPLITE: inuse 0
RAW: inuse 0
FRAG: inuse 0 memory 0
```

The values of sockets used always keeping increasing. By now, the number of sockets used have increased to 80k, and the real tcp online number is about 4k. I've configured the properties of openfire. I set the idle ping time to 30s which means if some tcp clients keep idle for a while, they will be disconnected. Through a lots of testing, it works well on my testing environment, but it does not work as well as my testing environment on the real server. How can I fix it? Or how to check it out?

Comment: You're leaking sockets. If you have code, post it; if you don't, you're off topic here.